# Redis-3.0.5 Sentinel on Windows

Tags: windows, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, sentinel

Trying to run the 1 Master 2 Slave with 3 Sentinel setup on localhost (Windows), using redis-3.0.5 64 bit, as described here :

https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-config.git

All instances come up fine and seems to be communication till I test the failover using the command :

redis-cli -p 6380 DEBUG sleep 30

this commands returns after 30 seconds during which the Master becomes unavailable and my Java app, using Spring-Data-Redis with Jedis client, goes into a connection retry mode.

There are no log messages on the console or log file for any of the Redis or Sentinel instances. No indcation of any of the 2 slaves being promoted to master.

The command "SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name mymaster" shows the same Master IP and Port all through the 30 seconds of sleep and after.

Am I missing something ?